# Is it possible to disable/enable mouseEvent using a push button?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

In my application I have two push button, namely "draw" and "stop".When the push button ("draw") is push by the user,he/she can draw or addItems in my QGraphicScene.I am using mousePressEvent to draw same position to my mouse.My addLine and addEllipse are inside my mousePressEvent. Is there a way where I can disable or enable the mousePressEvent with the push button so that If the user will push the "draw" button the mousePressEvent is enable while if the "stop" push button is press, the mousePressEvent is disable. If this is not possible, can you share any idea how can I implement and solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use variable to store state of your system, for example called `doDraw`, assign `True` in `draw.clicked` handler and assign `False` in `stop.clicked` handler, check value of that variable in `mousePressEvent` and draw only if it's true.